# How can I know my graphics card is performing as it should

Tags: graphics-card

So I assembled a PC last week, from parts I ordered online. From the start I was having problems with my graphics card, it was slowly dying.

I brought my pc for testing, and now they say my graphics card broke, and they will replace it with a new one. Now I am really worries there might be something wrong with the complete batch  of graphic cards.

Question:

How can you determine that the card you get is performing as it should. The card I have is a GTX660, so how do I know my card is actually any good. Maybe also in a way that I can say to the retailer that I am not satisfied with this card either if it performs badly.

Comment: Do you mean functional or performance-wise?

Comment: Did you try to search on a search engine?

Comment: Contact the manufacturer of the graphics card. They can tell you how to test it. If this is a new component, it should be under warranty and the manufacturer will replace it if it has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a tool: this has a free version http://www.3dmark.com/3dmarkvantage/ (see website as to what it offers).

You could also try http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/ or http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Benchmarks/FurMark.shtml which is free (please note, the 2 links here go to the same place, it's just provides an extra option if in the future a link dies)

This will also do it http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=214

I would also suggest the following Google searches (which is what I did):

graphic card test download
graphics card benchmark download